# Download all dependencies with yumdownloader, even if already installed?

Tags: yum, repository

Is there a way to download all dependencies with yumdownloader, even if they are already installed?

I'm trying to create a local repo and only want to include the packages we need.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `repotrack` instead like this:

```
repotrack -a x86_64 -p /repos/Packages [packages]
```

Unfortunately there is a bug with the `-a` flag (arch). It will download i686 and x86_64.

Here's how to fix it:

```
if opts.arch:
    #archlist = []
    #archlist.extend(rpmUtils.arch.getArchList(opts.arch))
    archlist = opts.arch.split(',') # Change to this
else:
    archlist = rpmUtils.arch.getArchList()
```

You can use `repoquery` to get a list of group packages:

```
repoquery --qf=%{name} -g --list --grouppkgs=all [groups]
```

Which you can feed into repotrack:

```
repoquery --qf=%{name} -g --list --grouppkgs=all [groups] | xargs repotrack -a x86_64 -p /repos/Packages
```

Comment: Updated to use repotrack instead. repoquery's `--requires` `--resolve` option doesn't work recursively for deps.

Comment: add the `--recursive` option to the repoquery command to get it work recursively.

Comment: Fixing repotrack the way suggested above did not work for me: no package was downloaded for x86_64 arch. Anyway +1 for a good tip: with repotrack one could download both i386 and x86_64 and filter out unnecessary part.

Comment: @Luke how to use fix part... means where to execute if condition mentioned... and what if i need to check for only certain package in repoquery command.

Comment: How do you invert this process and install the leaf package using the local dependencies?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to change the source code. If really, this is a bug, it should be filed into upstream `yum-utils` project. The reason why it downloads more packages than expected is because the function `rpmUtils.arch.getArchList()` returns all compatible architectures for the given one. It includes for example the `noarch` architecture which may be needed by `x86_64` packages. You can check the source: http://yum.baseurl.org/gitweb?p=yum.git;a=blob;f=rpmUtils/arch.py;h=d63ec2545d13efe0883ca0a84ccf410ebc8d4f3b;hb=HEAD#l213

Comment: How do we use the command? I tried putting the name of the package I'm downloading in place of `name` but it just says `Error: no packages specified to parse`.

Comment: With the `opts.arch` fix the args should include `-a x86_64,noarch` otherwise noarch packages won't be included in the download list

Comment: Using `repoquery --grouppkgs=all` will list every possible dependency (mandatory, optional, default) - note that these are not overlapping sets. Use `--grouppkgs=mandatory` for a minimal list.

Answer (score 24):

For everyone's information, `yumdownloader` does not do the job. For anyone with some experience in package management with `yum, it is natural to expect that the following command-line would recursively download a package RPM and all its dependencies:

```
yumdownloader --resolve <package>
```

But it does not. May be it prints first-level dependencies or those that are not already installed. I am not sure.

Here is one method that works on CentOS 6.5. Follow the steps to install the downloadonly plugin for `yum` as given by [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154). Basically, on CentOS 6.x, do:

```
$ sudo yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly.noarch
```

Then make use of the plugin in combination with the `--installroot` switch of `yum`. This prevents `yum` from resolving and then skipping dependencies that are already installed on the system.

```
sudo yum install \
  --installroot=</path/to/tmp_dir> \
  --downloadonly --downloaddir <rpm_dir> <package>
```

You would downloaded RPMs of the package, `<package>` and all its dependencies in the directory, `<rpm_dir>`. Example, with Git:

```
$ mkdir root rpms
$ sudo yum install --installroot=/home/roy/root \
  --downloadonly --downloaddir rpms/ git
```

Comment: How do you invert this process and install the leaf package using the local dependencies?

Comment: centos65 `sudo yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly.noarch` says `No package yum-plugin-downloadonly.noarch available.` what to do?

Comment: @HowardLee Running `yum search yumdownloader` returns `yum-utils.noarch`

Comment: I get this error `Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/$releasever/x86_64` when I add the `--installroot` flag.

Comment: Got rid of the `Cannot find a valid baseurl...` problem on Centos 7 with the solution on [this link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=850686): Add the `--releasever=/` parameter

Comment: what if you don't have yum installed? wtf

Answer (score 8):

Also try

```
repoquery -R --resolve --recursive <name> | xargs -r yumdownloader
```

e.g.:

```
repoquery -R --resolve --recursive firefox | xargs -r yumdownloader
```

Source: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/downloading-rpm-packages-with-dependencies-yumdownloader-vs-yum-downloadonly-vs-repoquery/

Comment: This one ended up being to only one that worked for me. `repotrack` kept finding packages that weren't available when I tried getting `wine`. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me on Centos 8, but I had to do the following (for docker-ce): `repoquery --required --resolve --recursive docker-ce | xargs -r yumdownloader` . As @Dan stated nothing else worked for me once I had Docker-CE already installed on the machine I was trying to get the dependancies from.

Comment: Note: I don't believe this downloads the actual top-level package (e.g., firefox for this example), so you'll need another command for that.

Answer (score 4):

If you're from the future (Fedora 23+), where yum is getting replaced with dnf, you might find [this bash script](https://github.com/picrin/rpmDownloader) useful.

rpmDownloader:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -xev
rm -fr packages
#dnf download $1 --destdir packages
export PATH=.:$PATH
echo $PWD
DEPS=$(rpmResolver $1)
dnf download $DEPS --destdir packages
rm -fr ${1}-dependencies
mv packages ${1}-dependencies
```

rpmResolver:

```
#!/bin/sh
goal=$1
deps=$(rpm -q --qf '[%{REQUIRENAME}\n]'  $goal | egrep -v '^(rpmlib|rtld|config|/)')
goals=
while true; do
  subs=$(rpm -q --qf '%{NAME}\n' --whatprovides $deps | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ')
  if [ ."$subs" = ."$goals" ]; then
    echo -n "$goals "
    exit 0
  fi
  goals=$(echo $goals $subs | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ')
  for sub in $subs; do
    subdeps=$(rpm -q --qf '[%{REQUIRENAME}\n]' $sub | egrep -v '^(rpmlib|rtld|config|/)')
    deps=$(echo $deps $subdeps | sort -u)
  done
done
```

Comment: Is it the future yet?

Answer (score 2):

I found that in practice building a repo like this difficult to maintain. We built this repo because:

- We wanted to pull packages from a local source for multiple servers.
- Only allow trusted packages to be installed.

The issues we can across were:

- Keeping packages up to date. Dependencies change. Some are added, others are removed.
- Adding new packages that we wanted to install.
- The above challenges lengthened the process of pushing critical updates.

In the end the better solution to *our* problem was to proxy the official repos and cache the packages we used. This works out well because:

- Only packages we actually use are stored locally.
- Old packages automatically expire.
- When a package is first used it pulls from the official repo, but subsequent requests come from cache.
- Trusting the official repo(s) was sufficient for trust. Our proxy mirror only pulls packages from trusted sources.

We used Nginx and the built-in proxy support.

Comment: nginx proxy sounds like a great idea. Better long term support and picks up more packages. Would be helpful if you added abit more details, maybe a how to link or something

Answer (score 1):

I realize the thread is old, but in case anyone stumbles across this, you  can use yum to accomplish the desired behavior.

First instally the downloadonly plugin(instructions for RHEL):
(RHEL5)

```
$ yum install yum-downloadonly
```

(RHEL6)

```
$ yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
```

Next run the command as follows:

```
$ yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/some/arbitrary/path [package]
```

If you ignore the `--downloaddir` yum will automatically download to `/var/cache/yum`

So unless you need to use yumdownloader specifically I think this would be the simplest way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: This is still an issue if package already installed

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Luke's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50671/6495) and the comments...

As of this writing `repotrack` will match all of the following architectures when `x86_64` is specified: `x86_64`, `athlon`, `i686`, `i586`, `i486`, `i386`, and `noarch`.

For my purposes I am only interested in `x86_64` and `noarch` packages, and I know that my distribution doesn't have any `athlon` packages.

The following command gets a list of package URLs, filters out `i?86` architectures, and prints out the names of the packages as they are downloaded:

```
repotrack --arch=x86_64 --urls gs1000-server \
    | sed '/\.i[3-6]86\.rpm$/d' \
    | xargs -I {} sh -c 'curl -s -O {}; echo {} | rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev'
```

Note that `repotrack` does not warn you if it can't find a package that satisfies a dependency in your enabled repos. It silently skips it.

Answer (score 0):

Yum's `yumdownloader`(1) refers installed packages information in the RPM database on the running environment as you know. It's very annoying.

I have a workaround that create `.rpmmacro` file to refer an empty RPM database.

```
$ mkdir home.dummy
$ echo %_dbpath $PWD/home.dummy/rpmdb >home.dummy/.rpmmacros
$ HOME=$PWD/home.dummy yumdownloader ...
$ rm -r home.dummy
```

DNF's `yumdownloader`(1) (is a symlink for `dnf-utils`) has no problem.