# Download ALL rpms for a product

Tags: centos, package-management, rpm

I have two CentOS machines, one 6.3 box (**A**), and another CentOS 6.1. (**B**)

6.3 box is with internet connection, 6.1 box is without internet connection.

I want to download ALL dependencies of a product on Box A, then copy those n Box B, and install the product.

I tried with

```
yum --downloadonly --downloaddir=*~/downloadrepo* -y install *product*`
cd *~/downloadrepo*
createrepo .
```

Then I disabled all repos (with --disablerepo), except my repo, and installed product on the same machine (Box A). No errors.

- `yum install *product*`

Now when I copied this repo to Box B, and tried to install with same command,
it starts installing, but then gives lot of errors like below:

> **Error: Missing Dependency: libldap-2.3.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package php-ldap-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 (installed)**

As there any way I can achieve what I need?

**UPDATE**

By the time I started working with option suggested by @rkosegi (*--releasever=version*), I was given a new box with same version CentOS 6.1 (**C**)

I tried above mentioned commands on Box C, and copied repo it to Box B. Still it failed.
The reason: though both boxes are 6.1, those are not identical (**uname -r** returns different strings).

Yum does not download dependencies, if those are already installed. So my repo did not contain some of the dependencies (including OpenJDK). So, when I try to install on Box B, it fails.

Quite frustrating!!!

But then I found command '**repotrack**' [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50642/download-all-dependencies-with-yumdownloader-even-if-already-installed).

```
cd ~/downloadrepo
repotrack -p . -a x86_64 product
createrepo .
```

I got a lot more files than with yum, hopefully it will do the trick.

I'll update, once I try install.

**UPDATE**

Command repotrack did not work for me. When I tried to install from repository created with 'repotrack', got following errors:

```
Error: Package: perl-CGI-3.51-127.el6.x86_64 (repo-local)
       Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-127.el6
       Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-119.el6_1.1.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201112102333.x86_64/6.2)
           perl = 4:5.10.1-119.el6_1.1
Error: Package: audit-libs-python-2.2-2.el6.x86_64 (repo-local)
       Requires: audit-libs = 2.2-2.el6
       Installed: audit-libs-2.1.3-3.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201112102333.x86_64/6.2)
           audit-libs = 2.1.3-3.el6
```

I tried removing these two files from folder, and rebuilding repository with 'createrepo'.
It gave another set of errors.

Not sure what options I have at the moment...

Comment: There is _no_ "6.1" CentOS. it is just CentOS 6 up to date to the moment when RHEL 6.1 was cut, probably with a lot of updates since.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do this a lot, you might want to take the time to set up [Spacewalk](http://spacewalk.redhat.com/). It will automate creating the repository and populating it with the appropriate packages (or, if you want, all of them). Not to mention everything else it does...

Answer (score 0):

```
yum --downloadonly --downloaddir=~/downloadrepo -y install product
```

You need to instruct yum to download from repository of same version as target machine(6.1)

Also make you need to make sure, that machine(6.3) which will perform download don't have already installed some of dependencies which are missing on target machine (6.1)

Comment: That won't necesarily work, as it will get the packages needed to install _on that system_. That could very well be a very different set than the one required on a (probably outdated) not-networked machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get a "clean" machine you either have to search manually for the missing parts with `yum provides` or

you have to go through your rpms that are already in you repo and query their dependencies:
`rpm -qp --requires RPM`. If that list turns up something new not already part of your repo, you have to add it.