# How to download a file from repo, and install it later w/o internet connection?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, repository

Assuming that I want to install a program called `leafpad` later.

Currently the only way to install it is via:

```
yum install leafpad -y
```

but I want to save this and install it later without internet connection.

How can I grab it from the yum repo and save it to a folder and then install it later?

Comment: I think the same question was asked over at super user, Here:
[http://superuser.com/questions/390384/download-local-copy-of-centos-yum-repository-for-offline-use](http://superuser.com/questions/390384/download-local-copy-of-centos-yum-repository-for-offline-use)

Comment: May I ask what is the benefit of doing this? :) One way to do this is to go to your repository URL via browser and download the package by hand.

Comment: @Alko that will not resolve the dependencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're only interest is in downloading a package + its dependencies for offline installation you can use the tool `yumdownloader`. It's part of the package `yum-utils`.

```
$ yumdownloader --resolve <package name>
```

#### Example

```
$ yumdownloader --resolve vim-X11
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vim-X11.x86_64 2:7.3.315-1.fc14 set to be reinstalled
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
vim-X11-7.3.315-1.fc14.x86_64.rpm                              | 1.1 MB     00:01
```

The above command shows the graphical version of vim, `gvim` being installed. Notice that it checks to see if you have the necessary dependencies installed, if not then it will download them as well.

#### What's the packages location

You can also find out what the URL of a given package would be using another tool included with `yum-utils` called `repoquery`. This is a fantastic tool and allows you to peer inside of repositories without having to download the packages that they offer.

For example:

```
$ repoquery --location vim-X11
http://kdeforge.unl.edu/mirrors/fedora-archive/fedora/linux/updates/14/x86_64/vim-X11-7.3.315-1.fc14.x86_64.rpm
```

**NOTE:** This URL is the URL from one of the repository mirrors, so it may change from run to run.

#### What else about the package?

You can use `repoquery` to answer these questions too:

What does a package require:

```
$ reqpoquery -R vim-X11
```

What does a package contain:

```
$ repoquery -l vim-X11
```

There's more consult the man page for `repoquery`.

Comment: What if my online system has some dependencies that are missing on the offline system?  Is there any way to make `yumdownloader` be more aggressive, and grab deps even if they're locally installed?

Comment: @Coderer - see here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50642/download-all-dependencies-with-yumdownloader-even-if-already-installed

Comment: that's perfect, thanks!  If you want to give that as an answer to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144870/can-i-yum-search-for-an-architecture-other-than-my-own) I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: @Coderer - I wrote it up.