# Can I `yum search` for an architecture other than my own?

Tags: yum

I'm trying to grab some packages from a yum server with `yumdownloader`.  I can pass the `--archlist=` argument to grab packages for a different architecture -- I need to in this case, as the target machine is running a 64-bit OS and my machine is 32-bit.

This works great, but `yum search` does not have a similar argument, as far as I can tell.  Is there any way to do wildcard search for the "wrong" architecture?

Comment: If memory serves, Fedora builds almost (if not) all its packages for all its supported platforms. I'm not sure why you'd need to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command line tool `repotrack` to download everything required by a given package. It purely looks at the repos so will download everything, regardless if it's already installed or not.

> repotrack - track a package and its dependencies and download them

#### Example

```
$ repotrack -a x86_64 -p . vim-enhanced
Downloading acl-2.2.51-10.fc19.x86_64.rpm
Downloading akmod-nvidia-331.67-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
Downloading akmod-nvidia-173xx-173.14.38-3.fc19.x86_64.rpm
Downloading akmod-nvidia-304xx-304.121-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
Downloading akmods-0.5.1-3.fc19.noarch.rpm
....
```

#### References

- [Download all dependencies with yumdownloader, even if already installed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50642/download-all-dependencies-with-yumdownloader-even-if-already-installed)

Answer (score 2):

It appears there is indeed no architecture option to use with `yum search`.  When I need to search by architecture I find `yum list` to be valuable though package descriptions are not available.

This is from the [man page for yum](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html#SPECIFYING_PACKAGE%20NAMES):

> SPECIFYING PACKAGE NAMES
>
> A package can be referred to for install,update,list,remove etc with any of the following:
>
> ```
>   name
>   name.arch
>   name-ver
>   name-ver-rel
>   name-ver-rel.arch
>   name-epoch:ver-rel.arch
>   epoch:name-ver-rel.arch
> ```
>
> For example: `yum remove kernel-2.4.1-10.i686`

Otherwise you could search like this:

```
yum search package | grep your_desired_architecture    ## i386, x86_64, noarch, etc.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the "wrong architecture" issue -- even though I've added a repository entry for a 64-bit only repo to my 32-bit machine, and set `exactarch=0`, `yum list ImageMagick.x86_64` (for example) returns no hits.  It works from a 64-bit machine, but not from a 32-bit machine.