# RHEL 7 - how to configure teaming on internet-less server?

Tags: rhel

I'm preparing to install RHEL 7 on my server. I read in doc that

```
The networking teaming daemon, teamd, is not installed by default.
To install teamd, issue the following command as root:
yum install teamd
```

By default my server is not internet-connected. Internet is available only via certain VLAN over LACP, so I have to configure teaming without internet.

- Is it correct that by default RHEL 7 doesn't have teamd?
- If so how can I install `teamd` without internet?

**upd** I also noticed that on CentOS LiveCD teamd **IS** installed by default. So I wonder what documentation means by "teamd, is not installed by default". Do they mean "minimal install" only? If I install "Server with GUI" will I have "teamd"?

**upd2** It's more a research question. I don't have working RHEL 7 environment right now to verify. If RHEL 7 has preinstalled `teamd` then I think the only question I have is why doc says that it is not.

Comment: The documentation likely is referring to that the RPMs are                     included with the media but are not installed. That's not an issue since you can mount the CD or the ISO on the system to retrieve the RPMs on the offline server when they're needed.

Comment: thanks, I guess this should work! So I should do something like this http://fritshoogland.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/using-your-dvd-as-a-yum-repository-on-a-rpm-based-linux/

Comment: Yes you can do that or put the ISO on the system when you build it and then mount it when needed: `mount -o loop rhel.iso /mnt` and then do yum local installs from that the media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you need this unless you're planning on teaming multiple network cards together as one.

*excerpt - http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeamDriver*

> The purpose of the Team driver is to provide a mechanism to team
>   multiple NICs (ports) into one logical one (teamdev) at L2 layer. The
>   process is called "channel bonding", "Ethernet bonding", "channel
>   teaming", "link aggregation", etc. This is already implemented in the
>   Linux kernel by the bonding driver.
>
> One thing to note is that Team driver project does try to provide the
>   similar functionality as the bonding driver, however architecturally
>   it is quite different from bonding driver. Team driver is modular,
>   userspace driven, very lean and efficient, and it does have some
>   distinct advantages over bonding. The way Team is configured differs
>   dramatically from the way bonding is.
>
> This feature consists of two parts:
>
> - kernel module (modules). They are already part of Fedora 18 kernel
>     package.
> - userspace library (libteam package) and daemon (teamd package).
>
> Although there is support for Team driver in initscripts,
>   the plan is to integrate Team devices handling into Network Manager as
>   well, probably for Fedora 19.

For downloading online you should be able to make use of the methods I describe in this U&L Q&A titled: [How to download a file from repo, and install it later w/o internet connection?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89222/how-to-download-a-file-from-repo-and-install-it-later-w-o-internet-connection/89250#89250).

Comment: that's right I need to teem 2 network cards (LACP) and to add special VLAN to have Internet access

Comment: Ah then you'll need to install this software prior. Hang on I'll get the command to download the s/w.

Comment: i can't even activate RHEL 7 so probably many commands will not work. I'm newbie to RHEL 7. I can't verify now if `teamd` is preinstalled. I guess it must be preinstalled, because CentOS livecd has it. But why documentation says that it is not preinstalled?

Comment: Do a `rpm -qa | grep teamd`

Comment: unfortunately i can't do anything right now. currently I have Windows only. I can experement on weekend only, because from monday to friday i can not reboot my Windows server. Next weekend I plan to try to setup dualboot RHEL 7 / Windows again. Now I just researching how to make it better, what should I do etc. because I have weekends only. I want to prepare. this weekand my girlfriend has a birthday and next weekand I have to visit my grandfather, so I don't have to much time and I researching now :)

Comment: @javapowered - no problem, we'll be here when you're ready to proceed.

Comment: I hope I will be able to verify that on Saturday, but if I will not be able to "tune" Linux for dual-boot Linux/Windows I have to clean everything and reinstall Windows once again. That's why I'm trying to prepare. So trying to understand IF `teamd` is not there and I don't have Internet - what should I do? Hmmm, alternatively, I can try to install RHEL 7 on some machine at home just to verify if `teamd` is there...

Comment: @javapowered - I'd install it on a Virtualbox VM to confirm. You can scan the RPM directory of the CD/DVD to see if the RPM's there too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17734/discussion-between-javapowered-and-slm).