# RHEL6 Compatibility Libraries and Development tools through RPM?

Tags: rhel

Is it possible to download the full RPM package for Compatibility Libraries and Development tools (RHEL6)? If so, where?

I'd like to keep it as backup for emergencies.

Comment: `CentOS` mirrors are best repos for their kin `RHEL`. Which libraries & tools are you referring to?

Comment: I'd like to get all the packages that a `yum groupinstall "Compatibility Libraries" and "Development tools"` should do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What's included in a package group?

You can use the following `yum` commands to find out the names of the various packages included in a package group.

#### Example

*Development Tools*

```
$ yum groupinfo "Development Tools" | head -15
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Group Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * epel: mirrors.servercentral.net
 * extras: mirrors.gigenet.com
 * updates: yum.singlehop.com

Group: Development tools
 Description: A basic development environment.
 Mandatory Packages:
   autoconf
   automake
   binutils
   bison
```

*Compatibility Libraries*

```
$ yum groupinfo "Compatibility Libraries" | head -15
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Group Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * epel: mirrors.servercentral.net
 * extras: mirrors.gigenet.com
 * updates: yum.singlehop.com

Group: Compatibility libraries
 Description: Compatibility libraries for applications built on previous versions of CentOS Linux.
 Default Packages:
   compat-db
   compat-expat1
   compat-glibc
   compat-libcap1
```

#### Which Repo & mirror?

All these packages are offered by any CentOS mirror. I believe you need to use care when mixing CentOS packages with RHEL, so you might want to go manual and use the command `yumdownloader` to acquire all the packages local and then attempt to install them, rather then installing them over the network.

Also the names of the repos that provided these packages is listed in the output above too.

#### Examples

```
 * base: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * epel: mirrors.servercentral.net
 * extras: mirrors.gigenet.com
 * updates: yum.singlehop.com
```

The names of repos are `base`, `epel`, etc. and the mirror that was selected for this particular command was `mirror.ubiquityservers.com`, for example. You can browse this URLs directory to find the packages you're interested in too.

#### Mirroring a Repo

If you'd rather you can use the command `repotrack` to just track an entire repo instead if you find that would be easier. See this U&L Q&A titled: [Download all dependencies with yumdownloader, even if already installed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50642/download-all-dependencies-with-yumdownloader-even-if-already-installed) for details.

#### Using yum-downloadonly plugin

You can also use the `yum` plugin `yum-downloadonly` to do something similar. Using the plugin would allow you to download just the package groups you're looking for.

Details are highlighted on installing and using this plugin here in this article titled: [How to use yum to download a package without installing it](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/10154).

```
# (RHEL5)
$ sudo yum install yum-downloadonly

# (RHEL6)
$ sudo yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
```

Then to download the RPMs related to a given package group:

```
$ yum reinstall --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> @"Developer Tools"
```

#### Example

```
$ sudo yum reinstall --downloadonly --downloaddir=. @"Development Tools"
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Reinstall Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.gigenet.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * updates: mirror.wiredtree.com
81 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Checking for new repos for mirrors
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package autoconf.noarch 0:2.63-5.1.el6 will be reinstalled
---> Package automake.noarch 0:1.11.1-4.el6 will be reinstalled
...
...
(21/23): patch-2.6-6.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                            |  90 kB     00:00     
(22/23): pkgconfig-0.23-9.1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                     |  70 kB     00:00     
(23/23): swig-1.3.40-6.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                          | 1.1 MB     00:01     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                 1.7 MB/s |  41 MB     00:23     


exiting because --downloadonly specified
```

The resulting directory afterwards:

```
$ ls
autoconf-2.63-5.1.el6.noarch.rpm          flex-2.5.35-8.el6.x86_64.rpm              patchutils-0.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
automake-1.11.1-4.el6.noarch.rpm          gcc-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm                pkgconfig-0.23-9.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.36.el6.x86_64.rpm  gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm            rcs-5.7-37.el6.x86_64.rpm
bison-2.4.1-5.el6.x86_64.rpm              gcc-gfortran-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm       redhat-rpm-config-9.0.3-42.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
...
```