# Centos7 - yum install downloadonly - Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: centosplus/$releasever/x86_64

Tags: centos, yum

I try to dowload `virt-viewer` package with all dependencies on Centos 7. I am using yum instead of [yumdownloader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174485/283188):

```
yum install --installroot=/tmp/ --downloadonly --downloaddir virt-viewer virt-viewer
```

**Error:**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
    just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
    --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

 4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: centosplus/$releasever/x86_64
```

I tried without and without `echo 7 > /etc/yum/vars/releasever` or uncommenting `baseurl` in my `etc/yum.repos/` repos without any success.

Edit: `yum update` and `yum downloader` both work so I guess I am a DNS resolution.

Comment: Is DNS resolving for this system? Can you dig records related to the URLs in the repo file? I would not mess with the variables and values in the repo file AT ALL unless you really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

I found this somewhere in a thread here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=850686:

When using --installroot everything is done within the chroot, so yum can't find out what $releasever maps to (it normally does this by reading /var/lib/rpm).

There are two workarounds:
- Pass: --releasever=6
- Pass: --releasever=/