yum download only for older RHEL version
I am trying to download a package and its dependencies for an older version of RHEL (on air-gapped machine) using yum. The issue is that yum appears be trying to resolve dependency conflicts against the system (which is a new version of RHEL).
/etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo:
...
[centos7-AppStream]
name=AppStream
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

[centos7-BaseOS]
name=BaseOS
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

Output of sudo yum install --downloadonly --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=centos7* --downloaddir=~/ nautilus-3.26.3.1-7.el7:
Error:
 Problem: package nautilus-3.26.3.1-7.el7.x86_64 from centos7-AppStream requires gtk3(x86-64) >= 3.21.6, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nautilus-3.26.3.1-7.el7.x86_64 from centos7-AppStream requires libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nautilus-3.26.3.1-7.el7.x86_64 from centos7-AppStream requires libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nautilus-3.26.3.1-7.el7.x86_64 from centos7-AppStream requires libgailutil-3.so.0()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package gtk3-3.22.30-5.el7.x86_64 from centos7-AppStream requires libcups.so.2()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package gtk3-3.22.30-5.el7.x86_64 from centos7-BaseOS requires libcups.so.2()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package cups-libs-1:1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64 from centos7-AppStream requires libcrypto.so.10()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package cups-libs-1:1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64 from centos7-AppStream requires libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package cups-libs-1:1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64 from centos7-AppStream requires libssl.so.10()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package cups-libs-1:1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64 from centos7-AppStream requires libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package cups-libs-1:1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64 from centos7-BaseOS requires libcrypto.so.10()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package cups-libs-1:1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64 from centos7-BaseOS requires libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package cups-libs-1:1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64 from centos7-BaseOS requires libssl.so.10()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package cups-libs-1:1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64 from centos7-BaseOS requires libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package compat-openssl11-1:1.1.1k-4.el9_0.x86_64 from @System conflicts with openssl-libs < 1:3.0 provided by openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64 from centos7-AppStream
  - package compat-openssl11-1:1.1.1k-4.el9_0.x86_64 from @System conflicts with openssl-libs < 1:3.0 provided by openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64 from centos7-BaseOS
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - problem with installed package compat-openssl11-1:1.1.1k-4.el9_0.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

Is there some other command line option for yum that I am missing to ignore the system configuration in gather dependencies?

Found the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50642/download-all-dependencies-with-yumdownloader-even-if-already-installed Needed --install-root
